# What is the proper way of opening a save as dialog when a button is clicked on site?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, file, model-view-controller

~EDIT MORE INFO~

I have 3 different file formats that I a user can choose from when a save button is clicked in the save as dialog.

The data is that needs to be saved is already stored on the back-end of the website (therefore there isn't any data in forms that will be required to be sent to the back-end).

Therefore do I trigger a function on the front-end (html, javascript) that calls a function on the backend (mvc controller function) that uses the data to output the save as dialog and have the choices to save in the 3 different formats. Or do I trigger a function on the front-end to get the data from the back-end and output the save as dialog (using javascript/html) on the front-end.

~END EDIT~

What is the proper way to open up the save as dialog when you click a button on a site?

It seems like using javascript is not the correct way to open the save as dialog. I am currently using MVC, so the question is do I have a button that triggers a function in the back-end (C# controller function) to open up the save as dialog?

I can't seem to find direct information of the proper (best) way to implement a save button, so any information, is much appreciated!

Comment: save as dialog for what?

Comment: ^ + you can't trigger any thing front-end (ie. a dialog) from C# code, as it runs on the server.

Comment: why Javascript is not the correct way to do this? I thing, this is the only way to do it. Even  a server side implementation will somehow use Javascript. Please specify details on why.

Comment: @epascarello & vivek I added more information. I am sorry I should have been more clear!

Comment: Nothing fancy needed on front end... can be done as simply as using a link to server path that would output as file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the save button post to a FileResult controller action. Whether the user gets a save as dialog, or the file just saves to the default download directory is up to the user's browser settings.

```
    public FileResult DownloadFile(int fileId)
    {
        byte[] fileContentByteArray = YourMethodHere(fileId);
        return File(fileContentByteArray, "MIME type goes here", "Suggested file name goes here");
    }
```

Comment: What if I wanted to force a save dialog because there are 3 different formats a user can choose from when they save?

Comment: what are the 3 formats? would you require a different file content for each? If I was doing it, I would give the user a set of radio buttons to select the format before hitting save, or separate save buttons for each format.